# Как заполнить двухмерный массив значениями из одномерного массива?

Tags: java, массивы, матрицы

Имеется одномерный массив, который я получаю из другого метода. Нужно заполнить двухмерный массив элементами из этого массива. Количество элементов может быть разным. Пример:

```java
int[] arr1; // здесь пока данных нет,
            // будем думать что они есть

int[][] arr2 = new int[10][10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < arr1.length; x++) {
            arr2[i][j] = arr1[x];
        }
    }
}
```

Этот код записывает только последний элемент из одномерного массива в двумерный массив.

Может кто-либо помочь с этим?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заполняем двухмерным массив `8x7` данными из одномерного массива `6` по кругу. Работает одинаково для больших и малых массивов не зависимо от размера:

```java
int[] arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

int m = 8;
int n = 7;
int[][] arr2 = IntStream.range(0, m)
        .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, n)
                .map(j -> arr1[(j + i * n) % arr1.length])
                .toArray())
        .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

```java
// вывод
Arrays.stream(arr2).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
int[] arr1;

int[][] arr2 = new int[10][10];
int count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
      if (arr1.length > count)
        arr2[i][j] = arr1[count++];
```